# Custom Flutter widget to return two widgets for use with CustomScrollView / slivers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, statelesswidget, customscrollview

I have a Flutter CustomScrollView with the following structure:

```
body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    MyCustomTitle(...),
    MyCustomSliverGrid(...)
    MyCustomTitle(...),
    MyCustomSliverGrid(...)
    MyCustomTitle(...),
    MyCustomSliverGrid(...)
    ...
  ],
),
```

`MyCustomTitle` extends `StatelessWidget` and in the `build` method returns a `SliverToBoxAdapter` widget, and the `MyCustomSliverGrid` widget extends `StatelessWidget` and in the `build` method returns a `SliverGrid` widget.

How can I implement a single Widget (`MyCustomSliverGridWithTitle`) that returns both the custom title and the custom SliverGrid? From the `build` method of a `StatelessWidget` I can only return a single Widget, not two.

Comment: I have the same problem and could not solve it, so I created [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77474).

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle `MyCustomTitle` and `MyCustomSliverGrid` into one widget with [MultiSliver](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools#multisliver).

```dart
class MyCustomSliverGridWithTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiSliver(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyCustomTitle(...),
        MyCustomSliverGrid(...),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```